# Why don't R Notebooks save/embed outputs in the file or R Project?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I send or receive an R notebook, or even an R Project (from RStudio), the R notebook doesn't maintain any of the outputs; neither printed text or graphics show up, and the whole notebook has to be re-run to show the outputs. Is there some kind of setting I can turn on to make sure the outputs are embedded in the R Notebook so that I can send the notebook to someone else, like with Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official RStudio community blog [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-save-the-console-in-r-studio-input-output/8118/2) (and my own experience with RStudio), this is not possible.

The RStudio blog's Sustainer however brought up two good points (although it does not solve your problem):

> If the purpose is to create a reproducible example, the [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package is the way to go. This is great for short bits of r code and output.

> You should also check our [rmarkdown notebooks](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html). Note that even with R's file >> save feature, you won't save plots etc. With rmarkdown or rmarkdown notebooks, you can intermix markdown formatted text, code, and code output (including tables and plots). You then also may knit that into html or pdf documents.

EDIT: if you are not tied up to RStudio, you can use [JupyterLab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/overview.html) instead (a powerful extension of Jupyter Notebooks - from the same project team). JupyterLab is language(kernel)-agnostic and does run nicely with R. All your work, included outputs, can then be fully saved - as you are familiar with in the Python world.

I used a cloud-based version of R JupyterLab hosted on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) but I am sure it can be deployed on your preferred environment as well (open source project, flexible, well supported by the Community).

Reference [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/overview.html)

> Kernel-backed documents enable code in any text file (Markdown, Python, R, LaTeX, etc.) to be run interactively in any Jupyter kernel.

Comment: Thanks! That's too bad. I know if I re-open the same notebook on my computer it'll show the graphics, but even if I rename the notebook the images are gone. It seems like the notebook maintains absolute paths to the images/etc on my computer. I thought by using R Projects it would maintain those paths, but I guess not.

Comment: Even though you cannot have this option in RStudio, I would recommend JupyterLab instead, if your working environment allows it. I have edited my answer with more info about this alternative. hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.